# Move linked files to TFS server to enable gated checkin and compilation

Tags: c#, tfs, continuous-integration

I have a solution with 3 projects. Project A generates a set of classes using CrmSvcUtil.exe. These classes are output to a file called 'Entities.cs'.

The other projects (B and C) link to this file as a shortcut. This means that the file doesn't ever exist in projects B and C. This compiles just fine as far as Visual Studio goes but when I try and check in the code to TFS and use a gated build it of course can not build project B and C.

What is the method for handling this? How can I get the files up onto the TFS server?

I have tried a Pre-Build xcopy of the file from Project A to project B and C but this does not seem to enable the TFS server to recognise the file and compile it

Answer (score 0):

You can set your project build order by right click on 'Project Solution' and select "Select Project Build Order" option, make Project A builds before Project B and C.